# MySQL unicode error with java web frameworks (Ninja, and Spark framework)

Tags: java, mysql, unicode, encoding, character-encoding

I first used Spark framework and ORMLite to process data submitted in a form on web page, and I saw the unicode problem when submitting Chinese characters. I first thought the problem may be due to ORMLite, because the charset of my MySQL database has been set to use `utf8_general_ci`.

So I tried the same form submission with the same MySQL data table by using Ninja framework, however, the same problem happens. The Chinese characters turn out to be "?????" (a string of question marks in the database field).

In my toy program, I have a model class named "Book", which has three instance variables:

```
Long id;
String author;
String title;
```

Accordingly, the html form has only two input fields: author and title.

I wrote the following method in my BookDAO class and use Hibernate to persist the data into MySQL:

```
    @Transactional
    public boolean postBook(String author, String title)
    {
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerProvider.get();

        Book book = new Book(author, title);
        entityManager.persist(book);

        return true;
    }
```

I have tried to change the charset of mysql to gbk (Chinese character encoding), but still have no luck of getting it to work. Another thing I've noticed is that the encoding errors only happen on my Ubuntu server, but not on my Mac server. This made me think what differences in these two OS's causes my problem with MySQL.

Comment: It's not at all clear where you're seeing the question-marks. This could well be a matter of just the MySQL tool you're using to look at the database, or how you're fetching the data. Using Java, can you fetch the right data again? Look at the Unicode value of each character in the string you fetch.

Comment: I use phpmyadmin as my UI to see the data stored in the database. I also have a java method that reads the data from the database, which presents a list on web page. The list of books output by java also show a string of question marks.

Comment: Okay, so you next need to check *exactly* where the data is being messed up. See http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/DebuggingUnicode.aspx and http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2014/01/20/diagnosing-issues-with-reversible-data-transformations.aspx (the first link is about C#, but the same principle applies to Java too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my encoding problem by doing either of the following. Both methods require restarting mysql

1. Log in to mysql terminal:

   ```
   >mysql -uroot -p
   mysql>use mydb;
   mysql>alter database mydb  character set utf8;
   ```

or do the following to change the charset of MySQL permanently:

1. edit my.cnf:

**> sudo vim /etc/mysql/my.cnf**

added the following entries to my.cnf

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8
[mysqld]
default-storage-engine=INNODB
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
```